# How is the process programmatically connected to an interrupt?

Tags: process, interrupt

I know that an interrupt is a signal sent to a kernel asking for handling. In some cases we have a physical device like a keyboard with a driver that connects a process with an interrupt(key pressed). But what about timers or other things that don’t have a physical device.
Maybe I have wrong thoughts about this all, and I will be glad if someone corrects me.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean when you mention "things that don’t have a physical device"? Timers come in all sorts of chips that can assert interrupt signals like any other. (Or equivalent modules inside a CPU.)

Comment: Maybe a timer is the wrong example, I meant pseudo devices. They don’t corrrespond to any hardware in the machine.

Comment: peudo devices like...?

Comment: Examples I remembered: dev/zero or dev/null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From one standpoint : whatever piece of code (microcodes included) running under a Linux system is running as a more or less immediate consequence of some hardware interrupt.

From the opposite standpoint : No hardware interrupt will immediately run anything else than kernel's internal cooking inside its hardware interrupt handler. The *interesting part* (understand from userland standpoint) will be *deffered* for later processing by some kernel thread.

And what is responsible for selecting what thread should be elected to run ? : The scheduler !

This being the very first answer to a possible understanding of your question : The scheduler is the component linking processes to interrupts, in that :

- It will eventually launch the kernel threads (ksoftirqd or whatever irq-dedicated ktrhead is system was booted irq-threaded) for processing the differed parts which would incidentally mark some events pending,
- it will then eventually launch the task that was sleeping waiting for this particular event.

Comment: Yes, I know about the scheduler, but my question is like what lines of code or programs used to connect the process to an interrupt. The scheduler is more like hardware answer for me.

Comment: @Duhan : In terms or processes, as written in my answer, only kernel threads are "connected to some interrupt" (I mean as immediately executing the deferable part of the job) If, by, "connected to" you mean something like how would whatever task be woken up when some timer elapsed then, as written above, the answer is : the scheduler would.

Answer (score 0):

From user space, the moral equivalent of an interrupt is a signal. A process can set up a signal handler, which is extremely functionally similar to an interrupt handler.  Most timers are handled this way with SIGALARM.  Historically, sleep() could be implemented with an alarm or with a system call that waits.

Some keyboard I/O is handled with signals.  For example, <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> generates SIGINT (2), but most keyboard I/O is not done this way.

Most devices, like a keyboard, are handled as files. Typically a process either waits for an I/O to complete with a read() call (and basically goes to sleep until the kernel scheduler sees the I/O has completed and wakes it back up), or it polls the open file for the device in between doing other things, or it gives the kernel a list of files and calls poll() or something similar to wait for one of them to complete I/O or a timeout to expire.

Additionally, keyboard (technically, tty) I/O can be handled specially using the termios library, which can adjust the way user input is buffered by the kernel, so that read() returns either complete lines or single characters or chunks of characters with a timeout.  (termios and stty can also adjust or disable the keys that generate the 3-4 keyboard generatable signals.)

There are multiple mechanisms like these that can interact within a process.  Signals can interrupt a poll(), and system calls like poll() and read() can either be interrupted or resumed after a signal handler.

Comment: "the moral equivalent of an interrupt is a signal" ??? Well… honestly… I won't state you are wrong. Only that… well… I just fail to understand… Hmmm… could be from a purely aesthetic standpoint… ;-)

Comment: If you've ever written an interrupt handler, a signal handler is extremely functionally similar.  The source of the interrupt/signal is very different, but the process side code to handle it is nearly identical.